# iOS modify "asset remove" Alert

Tags: ios, objective-c, assets

In iOS 8 you're allowed to easily delete assets from Camera Roll.
I already use this function in my App but I wan't to change the text of the alert, which is visible.

Image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhSAv.png

Now I want to change the title of the alert.
Did everybody know, what I have to do that i can change the title of the alert? 
I use Objective-C in Xcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a (sanctioned) way to modify the content of messages of this type where the iOS framework is cautioning the user about access to shared data.  This is for security reasons: imagine if someone changed the meaning entirely.  The user would answer a different question and the app could delete photos without the user knowing until it is too late.